# who creates the instance of FilterChainProxy?

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to understand functioning of spring security filters. I am reading the documentation and currently stuck at understanding who really inject the instance of FilterChainProxy.

I tried checking for -

- any auto config in spring boot if that creates this
- source code of spring-security to see if there is anything like  : new FilterChainProxy(..)

But no luck.

I found below in javadoc of class FilterChainProxy :

[image]

I tried checking if there is any xml config that is instantiating the class. But no luck here again.

Can anyone guide ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [stated by javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/WebSecurity.html), *the `WebSecurity` is created by `WebSecurityConfiguration` **to create the `FilterChainProxy`** known as the Spring Security Filter Chain (springSecurityFilterChain)*.

In `WebSecurity` class an instance of `FilterChainProxy` [is created](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/WebSecurity.java#L304) in `performBuild()` method using the constructor with `List<SecurityFilterChain> filterChains` argument.